# Search value and put in another cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want Excel online to put for example value of 0.01 for `eurusd` on this chart.

I cant figure out how to do this from another cells value.

I tried vlookup function but was unable to get it to work correctly in the table.

I want it to look at a column and input pip value auto if it can from the top of the Excel spreadsheet.

Here is my code but does not work in Excel online:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,{"AUDCAD","AUDCHF","AUDJPY","AUDNZD","AUDUSD","CADCHF"," CADJPY"},"CHFJPY","EURAUD","EURCAD","EURJPY","EURNZD","EURUSD","GBPAUD","GBPCAD", "GBPCHF","GBPJPY","GBPNZD","GBPUSD","NZDCAD","NZDCHF","USDCAD","USDCHF","USDJPY", "EURGBP","EURCHF","NZDJPY"},{0.0073,0.011,0.0071,0.006,0.01,0.011,0.0071,0.0071,0.0065,0.0073,0.0071,0.006,0.01,0.0065,0.0073,0.011,0.0071,0.006,0.01,0.0073,0.011,0.0073,0.011,0.0071,0.012,0.011,0.007})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$E$4,MATCH($B9,$B$3:$E$3,0)),"")
```

Put this formula into cell N9, then copy it down through N column.
I assumed you have values you want to find in B3:E3. If you have more of them, expand this range accordingly.

`$` in `$B9` can be omitted, it just allows the formula to be copied safely to another column.

Here is what you should get:
[The result of the minimum example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaVGy.png)

Absolute references (dollar signs) are necessary. Otherwise, ranges B4:E4 and B3:E3 would change, while they should remain unchanged in this case. For detailed explanation of absolute vs. relative cell reference see, for example, [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-and-absolute-references-981f5871-7864-42cc-b3f0-41ffa10cc6fc).

Comment: can I get rid of the dollar signs to make it easier to modify

Comment: how do I change N9 to a different box

Comment: it does not work for me for some reason

Comment: i figured it out it needs the dollar signs in the code

Comment: it shows a blank box in my other spreadsheet when i modify it works fine on my test one

Comment: i got it to show my forumula was not correct now it works

Comment: Yes, dollar signs are necessary. I edited the answer to clarify why they are needed.

Comment: @Elliot If this answer works for you, would you be so kind to mark it as accepted? 
You can mark an answer as the Accepted Answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer